# In an LWC, how can a function which is called from an event listener refer to a property of the LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

In an LWC I need to perform some logic when a postMessage is received from an iframe.  The logic needs to  reference an api property of the LWC which is set by a parent component.
I want to supply a named function when I add the event listener so that the listener can later be removed.

Here's what I've tried:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MikeComponentTwo extends LightningElement {

    @api
    someValue;

    someFunction(event) {
        alert(`Hello ${this.someValue} - ${this === window} - ${event.data}`);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener("message", this.someFunction);
    }
}
```

This produces

`Hello undefined - true - {"token":"03ANYol..."}`

So when `someFunction` runs, it doesn't know about `someValue`.  I added in the check on  `this` and can see that `this === window`.

How can I get around `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In writing out what I tried, and trying other things, I got it working.  It's likely a common pattern, so here's the working version.

When the listener calls the function, it sets `this` in the function to the object that fired that event, so window in this case.  That's not helpful as window doesn't know about someValue.

Arrow functions to the rescue!

Remember that arrow functions do not have `this`.  When you refer to `this` in an arrow function, "the lookup of this is made exactly the same way as a regular variable search: in the outer lexical environment."(1)

So re-writing the function as an arrow function means that it can now see `someValue`, and we have a listener, which can later be removed because it calls a named function, which calls that function, which refers to a property in the LWC.

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class MikeComponentTwo extends LightningElement {

    @api
    someValue;

    someFunction = (event) => {
        alert(`Hello ${this.someValue} - ${this === window} - ${event.data}`);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        window.addEventListener("message", this.someFunction);
    }
}
```

This produces

`Hello Mike - false - {"token":"03ANYol..."}`

If I add a console.log into someFunction:

```
    someFunction = (event) => {
        alert(`Hello ${this.someValue} - ${event.data}`);
        console.log(`this in someFunction: < ${this} >`);
    }
```

the console shows

```
this in someFunction: < SecureLightningElement [object d]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } >
```

so we can see that `this` is the component itself.

The following resources helped with understanding `this`:

(1) https://javascript.info/arrow-functions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913744/window-addeventlistenermessage-myfunctionevent-doesnt-work

https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-this-event-handlers/

https://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

This answer was posted on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com by Mike Arthur.  Any other sites displaying this content have not contributed to it in any way.